# Bake texture normals only (Blender 2.92)

Tags: textures, blender, texture-mapping

So I've been developing game assets in Blender, along with complex multi-materials I'd like to bake into a single map. Baking diffuse, roughness and emit textures works as intended, but I'm running into a bit of an issue with **normals**.

I was expecting all the normal textures I'm piping into my Principal BSDF shader would get baked -- and they do -- but the process seems to be taking my geometry into account as well. I was hoping there was a setting I could tick on or off to ignore geometry normals, but I can't seem to find anything, and all the tutorials I see seem to be using **cages** for ray casting; which makes sense if I was baking geometric detail to a lower poly model, but I'm only concerned about the texture normals in my materials.

My current solution is to pipe my normal image textures into an **emission** shader for flat/even lighting/colour, then baking it with **emit**, but I can't shake the feeling like this is unnecessary. I'd love to know if anyone else ran into this problem or can point out an oversight on my part.

Thanks in advance!